# How can you rotate/turn a crank in barrel organ?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, objects

I cannot quite figured it out how can you turn the crank and animate it? I tried parenting it to IK bone so when I move then hand it would rotate alongside but instead it just moves the crank without rotating it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turning the barrel organ handle -

[image]

The handle is animated to rotate.

The right arm hand-bone's 'Pole Target' (in Inverse kinematics) is set to the handle so it is forced to stick onto and follow the handle.

Comment: Thanks. Helped alot