# can the bone become a 'child of' a parent object?

Tags: animation, constraints, parent

I want to make the hands of the person 'track' the handle of object and I can't make the hand bone the parent using 'child of' constraint because my object is not fully merged together and when i tried the object just messes up. (different parts are just parented tgt to enable free rotation). Is there a way to do this properly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to use inverse kinematic with target.

Comment: Would this help?  -  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170592/how-can-you-rotate-turn-a-crank-in-barrel-organ/170702#170702

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your words when you say your object "is not fully merged together" and so you can't use a Child Of constraint, because that is exactly what I would do. Only I wouldn't make the hand the parent of anything (see below). I don't know what exactly it is that you are saying isn't fully merged, but given what you have described so far, I don't see why Child Of constraints wouldn't work.

I would create two empties that are parented directly to the handle in the position where each respective hand needs to grasp it. I would (G)rab and position the IK targets of each arm IK chain so as to be very close to each of these empties. Then I would create two Child Of constraints, one for each IK target, and point them to the empties, making these empties the target of the Child Of constraints. After clearing the inverse on each of these constraints, you should have hands that follow the handle.

Beyond that, you may also need to create two Copy Rotation constraints, one for each hand, and point them to the handle itself (not the empties) as their target, so that they will remain oriented to the handle whenever it tilts.

If you don't want to create empties, you could create a bone chain specifically for the handle itself. But if you do this, it should still be part of the original armature (add the bones in Edit Mode for the armature to ensure that these bones will become part of it), or else you won't be able to select this new bone chain in Pose Mode along with all your other rig's bones (you would have to switch rigs to select it in that case, which would be a pain). The new chain doesn't need to be parented to anything else in the existing rig, but you might want it parented to your root bone, depending on your needs for movement. Make it four bones in a line, and lock all their rotation values. This way, you can Child Of constrain your hands (IK targets) to the two bones in the middle of this chain, which will represent the positions of the handle where it needs to be grasped.

Comment: How do I make the tool have two parents though? The two empties you mentioned?

Comment: Nothing has two parents. Your IK target bones (hands) are Child Of constrained to the empties, and the empties themselves are directly parented to the handle. Now, if you found that you DID need more than one parent for any given object for whatever reason, Child Of constraints can actually do that also, since each constraint has an influence slider that can be adjusted independently of any other constraints. But I don't think you need more than one parent on any one object to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't make the hand bone the parent using 'child of' constraint
> because my object is not fully merged together and when i tried the
> object just messes up. (different parts are just parented tgt to enable free rotation).

A child-of constraint can be used for variable parenting, but nothing should have both an animated parent *and* a child-of constraint.  (Unless you're an expert doing something really weird, in which case, go wild, but you're probably on your own.)  A child-of constraint does not replace parenting; it acts *on top* of parenting.  This can have unintuitive results.

Instead of giving a parented bone a child-of directly, add a layer of indirection.  Create an empty and give your parented bone a Copy Transforms constraint, on default world->world settings; transform your empty appropriately such that your bone is posed how you want; now give the empty the child-of constraint and set the inverse.  This will replace parenting rather than acting on top of it.

Apologies if I'm not understanding your problem correctly.